# $V(x,y)=x^4-x^2+2xy+y^2$ Where does the solution tend to as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Consider the function $V(x,y)=x^4-x^2+2xy+y^2$ and the coupled
>   differential equations $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x},
>  \frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}$.
>
> Show that $V(x(t),y(t))$ is a non-increasing function of $t$. If $x=1$
>   and $y=-\frac12$ at $t=0$ where does the solution tend to as $t
>  \rightarrow \infty$?

I'm fine with showing that $V$ is non-increasing (just the chain rule) but I can't get anything after this, I've tried setting up some differential equations to solve but nothing works.

(We also had to sketch the contours of $V$ earlier in the question)

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain to me what does $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$ mean? This is nonsensical to me. If on LHS one has $x'(1)$, what would the RHS be?

Comment: @GitGud: I believe that if one adds the arguments then the equation should be $\frac{dx}{dt} (t) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \big( x(t), y(t) \big)$.